# How do I give the index column created by a functional groupby a name?

Tags: pandas

Given a dataframe where the argument to groupby is a function or a list of functions the resulting index column(s) has(have) no name(s)...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([['W',1,1],['X',2,2],['X',3,3],['Z',2,3]], columns='A','B','C'])

df.groupby(lambda r: df.ix[r,'A']).aggregate(np.sum)
```

returns...

```
    B   C
W   1   1
X   5   5
Z   2   3
```

How can I assign a name to the column containing W, X and Z?

(Note: This is an artificially simple example - the real function being used to define the groups is more complex).

Answer (score 1):

```
t = df.groupby(lambda r: df.ix[r,'A']).aggregate(np.sum)
t.index.name = 'foobar'
t
Out[7]: 
        B  C
foobar      
W       1  1
X       5  5
Z       2  3
```

Comment: if you want to add it has a columns you can just `t.reset_index()`

Comment: @Boud - Many thanks; No known way to assign the name to the function I guess?

Comment: @StevenG - I find the whole reset_index() thing baffling - it looks to me like a dirty hack to fix broken things?

Comment: the whole thing is your lambda function that is overcomplex, why don't you just `df.groupby('A', as_index=False).aggregate(np.sum)`

Comment: @Boud Because my actual use-case is more complex and requires the use of (*is much much simpler if I use*) a function to group.  Additionally if Pandas support the use of functions to group it's not (*IMHO*) an odd thing to want to name the grouping column produced.